# SOOMLA using jansson, and can't solve LNK2019

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, soomla

I am developing a game using cocos2d-x and SOOMLA as my Google Wallet extensions,
but SOOMLA uses jansson as its json parser; I included SOOMLA *.cpp,*.h and janson, but
while compiling, the following error occurs.

```
error LNK2019: Cannot solve unresolved external error _json_true
at function "public: static struct json_t * __cdecl 
CCSoomlaJsonHelper::getJsonFromCCObject(class cocos2d::CCObject *)"
(?getJsonFromCCObject@CCSoomlaJsonHelper@@SAPAUjson_t@@PAVCCObject@cocos2d@@@Z)
was referebce 
E:\projects\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\template\multi-platform-cpp\proj.win32\CCSoomlaJsonHelper.obj   WuXia
```

I'm sure I have added jasson project to my INCLUDE path, but it seems not to work.

Comment: Can you show your android.mk file

Comment: I don't have android.mk, because I use visual studio IDE.

Comment: you have any file where you are loading library of cocos2d-x

Answer (score 2):

Remove the folder `emscripten` from `external`. It solved many linker issues in SOOMLA in the past.

Comment: Thank you for replying. but I don't have this folder, I compile my project using Visual studio IDE, it occurs errors,but it now is working when using android ADT,  do you have any solutions? thank you.

Comment: Why are you using "Visual studio IDE" ?